# Sorted values in a collection only visible within a loop

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code that groups and sorts values within the anonymous collection. When I am in a sorting loop I see that values are correctly sorted. After the loop, they are still in unsorted places ..... why?

```
class Test
{
    public Guid P1;
    public int P2;
}

var Lista = new List<Test>();

Lista.Add(new Test() { P1 = Guid.Parse("D4651E83-67D6-4BCD-B28D-8173C5AE94F7"), P2 = 2 });
Lista.Add(new Test() { P1 = Guid.Parse("D4651E83-67D6-4BCD-B28D-8173C5AE94F7"), P2 = 1 });

Lista.Add(new Test() { P1 = Guid.Parse("310D74C4-0624-4B1C-9F4E-CB85924CB2B6"), P2 = 4 });
Lista.Add(new Test() { P1 = Guid.Parse("310D74C4-0624-4B1C-9F4E-CB85924CB2B6"), P2 = 3 });

var groups = from g in Lista
                group g.P2 by g.P1 into g
                select new { KeyGroup = g.Key, Rect = g.ToList() };

foreach (var x in groups)
{
    x.Rect.Sort((a, b) => (a.CompareTo(b)));               
}
```

Comment: you can order in select, like; select new { KeyGroup = g.Key, Rect = g.OrderBy(gi=>gi).ToList() }

Comment: What do you mean "they are still in unsorted places"? I am 100% sure that the `Rect` lists are all nicely sorted after the `foreach`.

Comment: @V0ldek, https://dotnetfiddle.net/8BlS15. hopefully you didn't bet. ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why?

Because the `groups` is an enumerable sequence and not a collection. Call `ToList()` or `ToArray()` on it before you iterate over it:

```
var groups = (from g in Lista
              group g.P2 by g.P1 into g
              select new { KeyGroup = g.Key, Rect = g.ToList() }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Then, Why is Sort available for a IEnumerable? Why does intellisense show that I have List<int>? That's all gives the impresison I work with List rather than IEnumerable

Comment: `Rect` is a list, `groups` is not. So you are sorting another `List<int>` than the one you are examining after the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Still don't get it. Maybe I am iterating over IEnumerable(groups) but I am getting access to List(Rect) which I actually sort. The same instance ...

Comment: No, `x` does *not* reference the same object as `groups.First()` in the first iteration in your example. The  `IEnumerable`  (`groups`) is not an in-memory collection.

Comment: Then ... what is x?

Comment: x is a local (loop) variable.

Comment: Furthermore no matter how I get access to inner List, still it is a list (allocated object of a collection type). When I sort collection I thought that no matter how I went for a collection, the positions of the items will be reflected. And they are reflected... but only in a loop. They does it mean when i sort I reference something else ??

Comment: `Rect` is always a list. `x` gets assigned to whatever value that the enumerable sequence produces when you iterate over it, but the groups are not persisted in memory so when you iterate over it again, you get new groups.

Comment: Ok maybe x gets assigned to any value, but shouldn't the rect reference be always returned the same?, where the list is actually stored in the memory?

Comment: No, each instance of a group have its own `List<int>`.